# Access EFI partition files in Linux

Tags: linux, partitioning, efi

I am using Arch linux in dual boot with Windows 10 and I want to mount the efi partition in Arch and to delete some files from there, like old Ubuntu grub file and so on... How can I mount this partition? 
Here is my HDD partitioned:

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1    8:1    0   300M  0 part 
├─sda2    8:2    0   100M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda3    8:3    0   128M  0 part 
├─sda4    8:4    0 129.2G  0 part 
├─sda5    8:5    0   835M  0 part 
├─sda6    8:6    0   200G  0 part 
├─sda7    8:7    0   400G  0 part 
├─sda8    8:8    0    67G  0 part /
├─sda9    8:9    0   7.6G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda10   8:10   0 126.4G  0 part /home
```

Comment: I smell an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)... Why would you want to delete files from the EFI partition?  Also, what happens when you try to mount it?

Comment: I want to delete some files from it, old Ubuntu grub file because in my BIOS those files appear as boot options, and I don't want that the boot options to became a long list of options and only some of them to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try remounting the EFI partition as RW. `sudo mount -o rw,remount /boot/efi`.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Grub-customizer. It is a GUI based program. From that program you can easily add and delete entries, use a theme for grub, use a background. You can also change the environment settings. Some people hate it, but I have worked with it since I became aware of it. I daily run Linux distros ( used to run Kubuntu, but since 20.04LTS is EOL switched to Garuda. Use Mint Una Cinnamon, Windows 10 in triple boot on one computer. The other one has Garuda, Linux Mint Debian Edition (Elsie) since yesterday, MX21 and Win10 ).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).